# Zoom not starting because of undefined symbol from libqtquickcontrols2plugin.so

Tags: debian, libraries, qt, zoom

I did a minimum debian stable system installation using `debootstrap`, but `zoom` is not able to start in such environment:

```bash
$ QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 /opt/zoom/ZoomLauncher


$ tail ~/.zoom/logs/zoom_stdout_stderr.log
    ],
    "version": 330752
}


zoom started.
loaded library "/opt/zoom/QtQuick/Controls.2/libqtquickcontrols2plugin.so"
/opt/zoom/zoom : symbol lookup error: /opt/zoom/QtQuick/Controls.2/libqtquickcontrols2plugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN13QQmlDirParserC1Ev, version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API
Something went wrong while running zoom, exit code is 127.
ZoomLauncher exit.
```

Seems that some `QmlDirParser` function from certain Qt_5 lib does not exist in my minimum installation environment, or the version doesn't match well.

Any idea?

My `zoom` is installed from the standard place https://zoom.us/client/latest/zoom_amd64.deb, and

```bash
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye

$ ldd /opt/zoom/QtQuick/Controls.2/libqtquickcontrols2plugin.so 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd875ee000)
        libQt5Quick.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5 (0x00007f5479215000)
        libQt5Gui.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f5478b53000)
        libQt5Qml.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5 (0x00007f54786f8000)
        libQt5Network.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f5478570000)
        libQt5Core.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f5478025000)
        libGL.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f5477f9e000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5477f7a000)
        libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5 (0x00007f5477def000)
        libQt5QuickControls2.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5QuickControls2.so.5 (0x00007f5477dbb000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f5477bee000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5477aaa000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5477a90000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f54778b9000)
        libQt5QmlModels.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5QmlModels.so.5 (0x00007f5477834000)
        libpng16.so.16 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f54777fa000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f54777dd000)
        libharfbuzz.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f54776f5000)
        libmd4c.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmd4c.so.0 (0x00007f54776e3000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f54776db000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f5477688000)
        libdouble-conversion.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.3 (0x00007f5477671000)
        libicui18n.so.67 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.67 (0x00007f547736b000)
        libicuuc.so.67 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.67 (0x00007f5477182000)
        libpcre2-16.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-16.so.0 (0x00007f54770f7000)
        libzstd.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007f547701a000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5476eeb000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f54799df000)
        libGLdispatch.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f5476e33000)
        libGLX.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f5476dff000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f5476d3c000)
        libgraphite2.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f5476d0e000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f5476c34000)
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f5476c04000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f5476bfe000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f5476bef000)
        libicudata.so.67 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.67 (0x00007f54750d4000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f5475061000)
        libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f5474f1e000)
        libbrotlidec.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x00007f5474f10000)
        libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f5474f09000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f5474eed000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f5474ec2000)
        libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x00007f5474e9f000)
        libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f5474e9a000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f5474c94000)
        libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f5474c7b000)
        libmd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmd.so.0 (0x00007f5474c6e000)

# All qt libs under my Debian bullseye, and their versions
 libqt5core5a:amd64_5.15.2+dfsg-9
 libqt5dbus5:amd64_5.15.2+dfsg-9
 libqt5gui5:amd64_5.15.2+dfsg-9
 libqt5network5:amd64_5.15.2+dfsg-9
 libqt5printsupport5:amd64_5.15.2+dfsg-9
 libqt5qml5:amd64_5.15.2+dfsg-6
 libqt5qmlmodels5:amd64_5.15.2+dfsg-6
 libqt5quick5:amd64_5.15.2+dfsg-6
 libqt5quickcontrols2-5:amd64_5.15.2+dfsg-2
 libqt5quicktemplates2-5:amd64_5.15.2+dfsg-2
 libqt5svg5:amd64_5.15.2-3
 libqt5waylandclient5:amd64_5.15.2-3
 libqt5widgets5:amd64_5.15.2+dfsg-9
 libqt5x11extras5:amd64_5.15.2-2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem. I did what [Eduardo Trapani](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/742540/211000) suggest, but did not work.

I solved uninstalling the last package (Version: 5.14.7.2928), deleting all files in /opt/zoom and reinstalling it. Previously it was installed 5.13.11.1288.

Comment: What was the version of zoom that had the problem, and what is the version that works? And, which package from where did you do the fresh reinstall?

Comment: I added the extra info :-)

Comment: Tq, with my +25

Comment: This answer didn't quite work for me; I was building by cloning the AUR package. The problem was I had files left over from a previous build which I guess were polluting the new build.

Solution: make sure to completely wipe ~/.zoom, /opt/zoom, *AND* the folder you're building the AUR package in!

Comment: @statusfailed That's the ticket, thank you! I'm using arch linux and had my left over AUR stuff sitting around. `rm -r zoom && ./updatepackage zoom` (`updatepackage` is my script that downloads then runs `makepkg`) got me going again!

Comment: @statusfailed you saved my life

Answer (score 1):

> symbol lookup error: /opt/zoom/QtQuick/Controls.2/libqtquickcontrols2plugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN13QQmlDirParserC1Ev, version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API

This has nothing to do which OS (debian stable) system or what's its installation method.

It's a problem of zoom itself -- zoom libs are self-contained and it does not require any libs from the underlying operating system. The version of zoom that had such problem was v5.14.2.2046:

```
$ apt-cache policy zoom
zoom:
  Installed: 5.14.2.2046
  Candidate: 5.14.2.2046
  Version table:
 *** 5.14.2.2046 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Today, I installed from zoom's official site a brand new version, v5.14.5.2430:

```
Unpacking zoom (5.14.5.2430) over (5.14.2.2046) ...
run post uninstall script, action is upgrade ...
Setting up zoom (5.14.5.2430) ...
```

but the problem persisted, exactly as reported above.

Luckily I have an older version which worked before, and when I tried it, it works just fine:

```
$ apt-cache policy zoom
zoom:
  Installed: 5.13.7.683
  Candidate: 5.13.7.683
  Version table:
 *** 5.13.7.683 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I believe the problem comes from the newly introduced `/opt/zoom/QtQuick` component from zoom v5.14+, whereas in my working zoom v5.13, there isn't such directory at all, only `/opt/zoom/Qt/`.

Comment: So far this is the only solution that worked for me. I used the AUR package for zoom `5.13.7-1`, which is at commit `44cbd9b5fb8444a446c28259012796bf3ac53beb`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `/opt/zoom` to the library path. In `bash` it would be:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/zoom:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and then run:

```
/opt/zoom/zoom
```

You could also put that in a wrapper script.

Comment: It should be the way for normal x-apps, and for such a reason, accepting it as the answer. But please note that it doesn't work for zoom, which was the reason why it took me so long to reply, I'll explain in another answer.